# Ip and Port Forward

Tags: unix, port-forwarding

We have three computers in our scenario. Lets name them A, B and C. There is no direct connection between A and C, you must follow A-->B-->C. I want to send soap request A to C. There can be a ssh connection between A and B. But no ssh server at C and i cant touch that computer because of security reasons. I just want to send soap request to http://computerCurl:8860/webservice. How can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that B can reach C on port 8860, and that A has no current listener on port 8860, try

```
A% ssh B -L 8860:C:8860
```

and once the tunnel is built, on A try "telnet localhost 8860", and check that you're connected to C's web service.